# <main> element doesn't take its parent height

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have remove all unnecessary elements of the DOM using chrome devtool.

body is relative and take all the space available in the document. This is what I want.

[image]

my toolbar is relative is and take the height I want :

[image]

The problem comes with my `<main>` element

This element is relative and have `height: 100%` property. If my understanding is good. `<main>` should take 100% of its parent. Here its parent is `body`. So `<main>` should take the space available.

In my case:

[image]

The `<main>` element has 0 in height.

Can you explain where it comes from ? And how to do to have this `<main>` element to take the available space ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this: `html, body {height:100%;}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html,body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Assign `display:block;`property to `main` tag because it wont work in IE

```
main{
     display:block;
   }
```

Comment: She/He is using Chrome though and said that `html` and `body` are both set to 100% already.

Comment: no ok my bad. body {min-height} was 100% but not height. It's working with body: 100%. Sorry for the bad info